# Не запускается сервер MySQL 5.6 x64 на Windows 7 x64

Tags: mysql, windows-7, apache2.4

Два дня пытался побороть проблему - никак не хочет стартовать сервер MySQL 5.6 **x64**.

Что имеется:

```
Windows 7 PRO SP1 x64 (исправно работает)
Apache: 2.4.38 x64 VC15 (исправно работает)
PHP: 7.3.1 x64 Thread Safe VC15 (исправно работает)
MySQL: 5.6.43 x64 (*не запускается служба*)
```

Что предпринималось *:

- всевозможные махинации с файлом hosts
- попытки запустить mysqld.exe со всевозможными ключами через cmd
- пробовал качать с оф сайта и инсталлер, и zip-архив (ручная установка)
- удалял остатки от старых версий в папках ProgramData, Appdata, Program Files, а также удалял все следы в ресстре, которые связаны с MySQL
- устанавливал все версии Visual C++ от 2005 до 2017, как x86, так и x64
- открывал TCP порт 3306 в брандмауэре, также пробовал вообще отключать брандмауэр
- отключал Apache (выгружал процесс httpd.exe)

*Ничего не сработало

Что увидел:

- при попытке запустить MySQL командой mysqld --console я ничего не получаю в ответ из консоли, а служба mysqld.exe не появляется в диспетчере задач
- при попытке установить MySQL командой mysqld.exe --install "MySQL 5.6" --defaults-file="C:\Web\modules\mysql\my.ini" служба "MySQL 5.6" не появляется в списке служб

Итог:

MySQL: 5.6.43 **x86** стартует без проблем и в тестовом режиме, и как служба, а x64 версия напрочь отказывается запускаться.

Хочется собрать для себя Apache+PHP+MySQL так, чтобы каждый компонент был x64. Что посоветуете сделать?

Comment: Так уже есть куча готовых сборок (OpenServer, XAMPP, etc)...

Comment: Хочу сам собрать. Open Server (OSPanel), XAMPP и прочее я уже ставил. Теперь ручками хочу собрать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится.

После нескольких ночей мучений с запуском MySQL 5.6 x64 я решился и поставил 5.7 x64 - запуск произошёл максимально быстро.

1. Запустил вновь 5.6 x86.
2. Сделал экспорт баз данных с помощью HeidiSQL 10.1 (с параметрами уничтожения и создания баз данных, если таковых не существует).
3. Через phpMyAdmin обратно импортировать базу данных phpmyadmin не выйдет, поэтому и придётся использовать HeidiSQL под Windows.
4. Закрыл процесс mysqld *32.
5. Удалил службу MySQL 5.6.
6. Удалил папку с MySQL 5.6 x86.
7. Установил службу от MySQL 5.7 x64.
8. Запустил службу MySQL 5.7 x64.
9. Сделал импорт баз данных с помощью HeidiSQL 10.1.
10. Проверил, всё работает исправно.

Конфиг my.ini:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[client]
default_character_set = utf8
port = 3306
socket = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/mysqlc.sock"

[mysqldump]
default-character-set = utf8

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 16M

[mysqld]
### Main variables
port = 3306
basedir = "C:/Web/modules/mysql"
datadir = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/data"
tmpdir = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp"
socket = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/mysqld.sock"
pid_file = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid"
connect_timeout = 10
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

### Charset variables
character-sets-dir = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/share/charsets"
character-set-server= utf8mb4
init_connect = "SET NAMES utf8mb4"

### Log variables
expire_logs_days = 7
log-error = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/logs/error.log"
#slow_query_log = 1
#slow_query_log_file = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/logs/slow_query.log"
#long_query_time = 2

### Type variables
default-storage-engine = INNODB
default_tmp_storage_engine = InnoDB
skip-external-locking = 1

### Buffer and Cache variables
innodb_autoextend_increment = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_concurrency_tickets = 200
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:2048M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 48M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_old_blocks_time = 0
innodb_open_files = 100
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 1
interactive_timeout = 30
join_buffer_size = 32768
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 20M
max_binlog_size = 256M
max_connect_errors = 3
max_connections = 300
max_delayed_threads = 0
max_heap_table_size = 112M
max_user_connections = 100
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
net_buffer_length = 8K
net_read_timeout = 200
optimizer_search_depth = 0
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 1
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
ssl = false
ssl-ca = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/cacert.pem"
ssl-cert = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/server-cert.pem"
ssl-key = "C:/Web/modules/mysql/tmp/server-key.pem"
sync_master_info = 0
sync_relay_log = 0
sync_relay_log_info = 0
table_open_cache = 4096
thread_cache_size = 4
thread_stack = 256K
tmp_table_size = 112M
transaction_isolation = read-committed
user = mysql
wait_timeout = 30
```

Перед добавлением службы MySQL 5.7 нужно в переменных средах Windows 7 добавить путь к папке с MySQL:

```
Пуск - Компьютер - Свойства - Дополнительные параметры системы - Переменные среды - Переменная Path - C:\Web\modules\mysql\bin; (именно с ; на конце строки)
```

Батник для регистрации службы MySQL 5.7:

```
mysqld.exe --install "MySQL 5.7" --defaults-file="C:\Web\modules\mysql\my.ini"
pause
```